solve Sympy functions in Scipy (optimize.root)
I'm trying to find the roots with the root function in Scipy for functions/variables created in Sympy.
sympy:
AllEquations = [x1 - 5, y1 - 5, z1 - 5, ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**0.5 - 150, y2 - 100, z2, ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**0.5 - 150]

AllVariables = [x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2]

Below works in Scipy, but is done manually:
def equation(p):
    x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 = p
    return x1 - 5, y1 - 5, z1 - 5, ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**0.5 - 150, y2 - 100, z2, ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**0.5 - 150

initial_guess = [5,5,5,100,100,0]

from scipy.optimize import root
sol = root(equation, initial_guess, method = 'lm")

>>>sol.x
array([ 5.00000000e+00,  5.00000000e+00,  5.00000000e+00,  1.20974135e+02,
1.00000000e+02, -2.00332805e-25])

Question is now, how can I automate this? The equation function above is static and should be made dynamically as the number of parameters and functions will change continuously.

Have you tried https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/solving/find-roots-polynomial.html ?

I have a solution with sympy, but it is very slow and it also gives you complex solutions, therefore I'm looking for other solvers like scipy. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/139734411?noredirect=1

You need to edit these constraints into your question - to ignore complex solutions, to prioritize speed, and that you are OK with numerical solutions at the expense of the accuracy of symbolic solutions.

This can be done using sympy's lambdify function to turn the equation into a Python function that can be evaluated numerically.
import sympy as smp
from scipy.optimize import root

x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2 = smp.symbols("x1 x2 y1 y2 z1 z2")
variables = [x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2]

equations = [x1 - 5,
             y1 - 5,
             z1 - 5,
             ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**0.5 - 150,
             y2 - 100,
             z2,    
    ]

# this list will contain all the functions you want to find the roots of
equations_lamb = [smp.lambdify(variables, eq) for eq in equations]

def combined_function(x, function_list):
    # evaluates the provided list of functions
    res = []
    for function in function_list:
        res.append(function(*x))
    return res

initial_guess = [0]*len(variables)
sol = root(combined_function, initial_guess, args=(equations_lamb,))
print(sol)


Hello @jared, this works as expected. I'm also looking into the other proposed solution. thanks.

I checked this for now as the correct answer because it is a lot faster than the solution with the Jacobian on some small tests. I will see how this evaluates on a real test with a lot more functions.

tip, If the number of equations is less than the number of variables, you can just append 0's to the list of equations so it is not longer undetermined. Ps.: Sympy gives you all possible solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342734/scipy-optimization-for-under-constrained-system?rq=4

Adding equations of just zeros does not change whether a system of equations is underdetermined.


how can I automate this?

The concept is ill-defined. To a certain extent, you can't fully automate this, because you need sane initial estimates for a well-behaved root-find. There is not a one-size-fits-all. If you write a sympy-to-scipy wrapper, you still need to be able to adjust parameters like the method and tolerance.
Since you're in Sympy, there's a good chance that it will be able to calculate a Jacobian for you, and you should definitely do that.
Don't call lambdify once per equation; just call it once on a vector (Matrix) of all of your equations.
import typing

import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize
import sympy
from scipy.optimize import root, check_grad


def numerical_roots(
    symbolic_eqs: typing.Sequence[sympy.Eq],
    x0: dict[str, float],
    method: typing.Literal[
        'hybr', 'lm', 'broyden1', 'broyden2', 'anderson', 'linearmixing', 'diagbroyden',
        'excitingmixing', 'krylov', 'df-sane',
    ] = 'hybr',
    tol: float | None = None,
    jac_tol: float | None = 1e-5,
) -> tuple[scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult, dict[str, float]]:
    matrix = sympy.Matrix([
        eq.args[0] - eq.args[1]
        for eq in symbolic_eqs
    ])
    syms = tuple(matrix.free_symbols)
    jacmat = matrix.jacobian(syms)
    eq_unpacked = sympy.lambdify(args=syms, expr=matrix)
    jac_unpacked = sympy.lambdify(args=syms, expr=jacmat)
    numeric_x0 = [x0[s.name] for s in syms]

    def eq_packed(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        return eq_unpacked(*x).ravel()
    def jac_packed(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        return jac_unpacked(*x)

    if jac_tol is not None:
        jerr = check_grad(func=eq_packed, grad=jac_packed, x0=numeric_x0)
        if jerr > jac_tol:
            raise ValueError('Jacobian is incorrect')

    result = root(
        fun=eq_packed, jac=jac_packed,
        x0=numeric_x0, method=method, tol=tol,
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)
    return result, {
        s.name: x
        for s, x in zip(syms, result.x)
    }


def test() -> None:
    a = {'real': True, 'finite': True}
    x1 = sympy.Symbol(name='x1', **a)
    y1 = sympy.Symbol(name='y1', **a)
    z1 = sympy.Symbol(name='z1', **a)
    x2 = sympy.Symbol(name='x2', **a)
    y2 = sympy.Symbol(name='y2', **a)
    z2 = sympy.Symbol(name='z2', **a)
    equations = (
        sympy.Eq(5, x1),
        sympy.Eq(5, y1),
        sympy.Eq(5, z1),
        sympy.Eq(150, sympy.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)),
        sympy.Eq(100, y2),
        sympy.Eq(0, z2),
    )
    for method in (
        'hybr', 'lm', 'broyden2', 'anderson', 'krylov',
    ):
        result, sol = numerical_roots(
            symbolic_eqs=equations, method=method,
            x0={'x1': 1, 'y1': 1, 'z1': 1, 'x2': 1, 'y2': -1, 'z2': -1},
        )
        assert np.isclose(sol['x1'], 5, rtol=0, atol=1e-5)
        assert np.isclose(sol['y1'], 5, rtol=0, atol=1e-5)
        assert np.isclose(sol['z1'], 5, rtol=0, atol=1e-5)
        if sol['x2'] > 0:
            assert np.isclose(sol['x2'], 120.97413504743209, rtol=0, atol=1e-5)
        else:
            assert np.isclose(sol['x2'], -110.97413504743206, rtol=0, atol=1e-5)
        assert np.isclose(sol['y2'], 100, rtol=0, atol=1e-5)
        assert np.isclose(sol['z2'], 0, rtol=0, atol=1e-5)
        print(f'method={method} nfev={result.nfev} njev={result.get("njev")} status={result.status}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()

method=hybr nfev=13 njev=1 status=1

method=lm nfev=12 njev=8 status=2

C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_root.py:255: RuntimeWarning: Method broyden2 does not use the jacobian (jac).
  _warn_jac_unused(jac, method)
method=broyden2 nfev=100 njev=None status=1

C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_root.py:255: RuntimeWarning: Method anderson does not use the jacobian (jac).
  _warn_jac_unused(jac, method)
method=anderson nfev=344 njev=None status=1

C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_root.py:255: RuntimeWarning: Method krylov does not use the jacobian (jac).
  _warn_jac_unused(jac, method)
method=krylov nfev=418 njev=None status=1


hello @Reinderien. Sorry for my ill-defined question. To converges as expected, initial estimates are very important. Those will be provided from the user who draws his approximate lines, which will be used as initial estimates as in in sketch, but here it will be in 3D. I'm trying to get your solution to work. First, because I'm using Python 3.8.17 not all hinting works, but this is easily solved. Second, I get the following error in numerical_roots jerr = check_grad(func=eq_packed,  rad=jac_packed, ...)  ValueError: The user-provided objective function must return a scalar value. Thanks,

@AchaibouKarim upgrade your stack. It doesn't make sense for the Jacobian to return a scalar.

thanks @Reinderien, this solved the problem. Many thanks.
